# string allocation in C++: why does this work?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

```
void changeString(const char* &s){
    std::string str(s);
    str.replace(0, 5, "Howdy");
    s = str.c_str();
}

int main() {
    const char *s = "Hello, world!";
    changeString(s);
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it prints "Howdy, world!" I would think that `str` gets destroyed when `changeString` exits. Am I missing something with the way `std::string` gets allocated?

Comment: I *guess* this *happened* to work.

Comment: Sometimes undefined behavior appears to work. You shouldn't ever expect this to work, however.

Comment: Bad luck. You're right that it's wrong.

Comment: You don't do anything that would re-allocate and overwrite the deleted chunk in before you use that chunk and implementations rarely invalidated deleted-chunks by returning them to the system, so your example is quite likely to happen to work, but it's undefined behavior nonetheless. You should `return` the string.

Comment: I want to tell you to use appropriate tools, but none of [ASan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), [UBSan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html), gdb or [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) catch anything. How sad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, str is destroyed; but the memory of the string isn't cleared; your "s" pointer point to a free but non cleared memory. Very dangerous.

Answer (score 14):

It's **undefined behaviour** when `std::cout << s` tries to access the pointer, because the destructor of the local `std::string` in `changeString` has freed the memory which the pointer still points to.

Your compiler is not required to diagnose the error but can instead generate a binary which can then do whatever it wants to.

The fact that you got the desired output was just bad luck because it made you *think* that your code was correct. For instance, I've just compiled your code on my machine and got empty output instead. It could also have crashed, or it may have done other, unrelated things.